# SQL Server 2008 R2 wait types- 'PREEMPTIVE_OS%'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Where can i find documentation about wait types (SQL Server 2008 R2):

```
Select * from sys.dm_os_wait_stats  where wait_type like 'PREEMPTIVE_OS%'
```

For example "PREEMPTIVE_OS_CRYPTIMPORTKEY".
there is no such wait type documented in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179984%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQL Server normally runs threads in cooperative multitasking.  When it calls to the OS, it has to change to preemptive multitasking.  So a `PREEMPTIVE_OS%` wait means SQL Server is waiting for the OS to do something.

You can find documentation for the thing it's waiting on by stripping the `PREEMPTIVE_OS_` part.  For example, the documentation for `CryptImportKey` can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380207%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).